# VirtualBox - ports other than 80 do not work

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, port, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running inside Oracle VirtualBox machine. I have IIS installed and can access the default website from my computer: `http://machinename`

The problem is that when I add or change a binding to other port than 80 (e.g. 8001), I cannot access the website from my computer (e.g. `http://machinename:8001`). Port 80 works, other do not.

How do I configure IIS inside of VirtualBox to serve pages to ports other than 80?

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled?

Comment: I tried with both firewalls (on my machine and on server virtual machine) turned off. With the same results :-(   I do not know if I have something missconfigured on the server of it is a problem of VirtualBox...